How to create a csv file using SSRS with 2 distinct header rows and 2 rows of data for each record (template format in question)
I'm attempting to build a self-service report to produce a csv in a template format which will be uploaded to a finance system.
The template dictates that each record, in this case learners, should appear across 2 rows of data. The values in these rows include some matching and some differing values.
In addition the csv requires 2 distinct header rows, which align with the data rows.
There needs to be a blank rows in-between each learner (reference).
See below the first 6 columns required in the csv template with 3 example references.
Note The orphaned header above the table is also required as a header row (the table format in this insert doesn't allow 2 header rows).
| Type| Reference| Vendor No| Amount| Description| Borough|



Type
Reference
VAT code
Amount
Description
Cost centre




AP
758375000000
D000000016
128
758375-DLSF Payment
WCC


GL
758375000000
V0
128
758375-DLSF Payment
W22003










AP
563753000000
D000000016
20
563753-DLSF Payment
WCC


GL
563753000000
V0
20
563753-DLSF Payment
W22003










AP
421765000000
D000000016
56
421765-DLSF Payment
WCC


GL
421765000000
V0
56
421765-DLSF Payment
W22003



My first attempt was inserting 2 separate Tables, one immediately after the other, with the 'AP' values in the first, and the 'GL' values in the second. However, the resulting output grouped all learner's AP rows together, and then the GL rows.
Inserting a List inside of a Rectangle, with all of the fields inserted across 4 rows, got me much closer to the template format in an Excel export only. However, the spreadsheet output included hidden columns in-between the populated columns, and many of cells were merged. Therefore if I attempted to save the file as a csv the format was completely lost.
Almost all reports I've created previously in SSRS have used tables for data grids. Therefore any advice on the best approach in this instance would be hugely welcomed.

can you show the final look of the csv you expect to see at the end of this process?

Hi Harry, thanks for following up. Here's a link to the csv template format required (via github):  https://github.com/BigJ83/files/blob/main/Payment%20Template.csv

Adding a tag @Harry as it wasn't in previous comment

what do you use for data ? SQL Server?

Assuming you are using SQL SERVER for your data, I have come up with a "Hacky" way of doing this.
The idea is to select the data you need, sorting and assigning row numbers to each row. You then manipulate the row number and  union the results with blank data and then finally reordering it.
After this step, you further union it with column header text.
See the SQL Fiddle link below for the full code.. it might not be 100%, but it's close enough for you to do some work to get it to where you want it..
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=c2c1deb8-a3b8-4aef-aebb-f48740debc52

Hi @Harry. Thanks for taking the time to put this code together. I am indeed using SQL, and this solution would work great if the csv template required fixed values. However, as per my original query, I'm required to design a SSRS self-service report which generates the csv.  The resulting report will have parameters allowing the user to select different learners from our database and generate them in a csv file in this specific format.

Well, the data that is used in the query is obviously just a sample (from your original sample)!. I don't see why the data you select with parameters should be any different.. (sure different content but same or similar schema right?)

Apologies that was a moment of brain fog, I shouldn't have replied after a long day. Of course I'll be able to replace the data with report fields/parameters.  I've been playing with the query this morning, and it's fantastic. I've tweaked it so I can have different values in the two 'header' rows, so now I'll be able to use this as the basis for my SSRS report. Harry, thanks so much. I can't even upvote your answer as I'm quite new here, but rest assured you've really helped me out when I wasn't sure how to progress.

@JoeG glad to help. Please accept the answer if you though it did most if not all of the job.

Hi @Harry. Sorry to revisit this, but I've had issues producing the required csv when attempting to add parameters. I created a report version of the script you provided with tables and where clauses, where the fixed values are replaced by database fields. This has changed the format of the output, with the learners (references) getting displayed on multiple lines, and the rows - AP, GL, NULL - appearing in the wrong order.  If you have any time to help again, would it be possible to try adding database fields and a where clause to your example to see if get the same result?

I'm hesitant to share the specific new SQL code due to data protection as it's from my organisation's database, but here's a link to an example of the latest output: https://github.com/BigJ83/files.git ('Example Output.csv). Many thanks

I'm assuming you are running a stored procedure to return the data. If you run your SP with the parameters, does SQL return the data in the order you need it to?

No I’m building an SSRS report in which this query is the dataset, and parameters allow users to select learners (references) based on a range of criteria. The csv ouput is a monthly return, so different learners will need to be selected each time. However, even when testing the code in SQL Server, the data is returned with erroneous additional lines and in the wrong order as soon as I add a where clause (as per the example ouput).

I understand you are building an SSRS report. What we are focusing here is on the dataset and use SSRS to simply display the results ( or in your case export the CSV). You can use a stored procedure as your datasource.. Wrap your SQL query into a stored procedure. What are the parameters that are supplied by the end user? I'm failing to understand how a where clause would cause erroneous lines. Not knowing what your actual SQL looks like and why your underlying data is returning the way it is.. it makes it hard to help!

I've now got the authorisation to share my SQL code Harry, see file 'Finance Upload Query' in github.com/BigJ83/files.git. The data rows are now combined in a single union, and there's a where clause picking up specific person codes (learners). This was just for testing; in the SSRS report the end user will determine the learners with a created date parameter (the field which in the outer apply join). The updated 'Example Output' shows the results from this code.

The first CTE, base_table, can you confirm that it always return 2 records per student? One with AP and one with GL

Nope it produces inconsistent results, sometimes with the correct 2 rows per learner and in other cases with 4 rows. The learners with 4 rows have 2 AP rows together and 2 GL rows together either side of a NULL row.
You can see this in the example output file, which shows the results for the 3 learners in the where clause from the first CTE.

Is that an acceptable outcome of the query? looking at 516502 and 316620, both the AP and GL lines appear to be duplicates .. is this acceptable for the extract? If not, it could be the result of a left join that is returning duplicates.. or it could simply be a case of adding a distinct select. can you confirm this

As the file is required for a system upload the csv is dictated by a strict format, so the duplicates are not acceptable unfortunately. However, I hadn't actually tried the simple addition of adding a select distinct. To my surprise this resolved the issues- not only did it remove the duplicate lines, but all learners now appear in the correct order (AP, GL then a NULL row). The code is now definitely report ready! Again thanks so much @Harry, you’ve really helped myself and the business here.
